# How to retrieve objects from firebase by key value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm new to firebase and I have such structure of my firebase project

[image]

I want to get all objects, that "Interested" value is  equal to "men"

I wrote such code, to get all object sorted by interes value:

```
let thisUserRef = URL_BASE.childByAppendingPath("profile")

thisUserRef.queryOrderedByChild("Interest")
     .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

     if let UserInterest = snapshot.value!["Interest"] as? String {    
          print (snapshot.key)  
     }
}
```

But I receive nil.

Answer (score 3):

you need to loop through all the **key-value** profiles

```
      if let allProfiles = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for (_,profile) in allProfiles {
                  print(profile);
                  let userInterest = profile["Interest"]
           }
       }
```

Here _ is the key that is in the format `KYXA-random string` and profile will be the element for that key.

**Edit**:

There is querying for child values as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#sort_data).

Try `thisUserRef.queryOrderedByChild("Interest").equalTo("men")` and then using the inner loop that i specified in the answer

Comment: Ok, thx! But actually I need to receive ojects, that satisfy my condition userInterest == "men". I tried to write if statement and print(profile) but I got nil

Comment: This answer won't work. Snapshot.value isn't a string, it's a dictionary. Also, the OP wants all of the user nodes that Interest = men. Also, if there are 10,000 nodes, this may overwhelm the memory of the device. It's better to just retrieve the nodes of interest via a query.

Comment: It actually will be a string-object dict if you use normal `.Value` retrieve - i have tested it. Although your answer does explain querying which is correct.

Comment: I stand corrected! The code does in fact work and could potentially provide a solution. It's not the 'best' process but it's certainly good to know!

Comment: As a side note, by reading the data in this way, they are being read into a dictionary, which is unordered so you will loose the ordering (Firebase orders naturally by Key). It should be iterated over with child in snapshot.children

Comment: docs actually do not have any reference of using `children` and in fact uses snapshot.value in each case.

Comment: @FrankVanPufflen From a firebase staff [snapshot.children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734164/ios-firebase-loop-all-key-in-snapshot-value-get-messy-position/36746115#36746115)

Comment: yeah, i saw children being used on the android side but the iOS one uses snapshot.value in doc. FrankVanPufflen seem to be proficient in Android and therefore could have used it that way (knowing the inner details). I am just answering following their iOS docs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic query in Firebase. (Updated for Swift 3, Firebase 4)

```
    let profileRef = self.ref.child("profile")
    profileRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "Interest").queryEqual(toValue: "men")
    profileRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let dict = child as! [String: Any]
            let name = dict["Name"] as! String
            print(name)
        }
    })
```

The legacy documentation from Firebase really outlines how to work with queries: find it here

[Legacy Firebase Queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html)

The new documentation is pretty thin.

Oh, just to point out the variable; thisUserNode should probably be profileRef as that's what you are actually query'ing.

Comment: i have a question about this! This code works, and if i want to remove this child.value["Name], how do i do?