# Swift How to change an outside object value in a withBlock statement

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

i have a problem about How to change an outside object value in a withBlock statement.

Here is my code:

```
func finduserbyid(uid: Int) -> User{
    var current_user = User()
    let display_ref = self.users_ref.child(String(uid))
    display_ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(snapshot) in      

        let current_user_dic =  snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        current_user.uid = current_user_dic["uid"] as! Int
    })
        { (error) in
            print (error)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    return current_user
}
```

this is a function that i try to pull a userinfo out of firebase snapshot func.

i find that the function did get run into the change user.uid line.
but the returned object user always empty

please someone point out what part is wrong.

Had this question like a month ago.

Still not figured out the solution.

And this function only get run in the first viewcontroller if i try to run it in other viewcontrollers with the same input it will throw me an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and according to my breakpoint the error happends in this line of code.

```
display_ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(snapshot) in
```

this is the print current_user_dic outputs inside the withblock code

```
{

age = 0;

chats =     (

    0

);

"course_enroll" =     (

    ""

);

"create_time" = "1466705475370.6";

department = "";

"display_name" = "HL";

"email_address" = "xxxx@gmail.com";

"follow_count" = 0;

"follow_list" =     (

    0

);

"follower_count" = 0;

"follower_list" =     (

    0

);

friendlist =     (

    0

);

gender = "";

history =     (

    0

);

language = "";

level = 0;

phone = 0;

"rating_point" = 0;

reputation = 0;

"signed_events" =     (

    0

);

uid = 101;
```

}

and i did notice the function always runs twice, first stright to error handle, second time will go through the main body.
 i called it in my viewcontroller like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
let user = database.finduserbyid(101)
print(user.display_name)
print(user.email_address)
print("1")
```

Comment: not really clear to me. what is change user.uid line ?

Comment: current_user.uid = current_user_dic["uid"] as! Int                 this line of code

Comment: it will be nil. see this to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639601/how-to-retrieve-objects-from-firebase-by-key-value/37639623#37639623

Comment: Sorry i dont really understand why my user object didn't get modified. it still empty.

Comment: `print(current_user_dic)` to check if the dictionary actually has values

Comment: That is some artistic indentation you've got going n there

Comment: yea all the values are in the dic

Comment: update the question with the values you see

Comment: edited.................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how Firebase works and don't try to leverage Firebase as 'functions' as that's not what it does.

Firebase is asynchronous and the current_user may be returned before the snapshot is populated from Firebase and can assign the data to the current_user var. That's why you are getting nil - the the return executed before the snapshot returned.

Keep in mind that local code on your device runs WAY faster than the internet so you have to write code that allows the data to be returned in the snapshot before doing something with it.

You can't* return values from Firebase calls - let Firebase do the heavy lifting for you.

```
var currentUserName = String()
let thisUserRef = usersRef.childByAppendingValue("some_uid")
thisUserRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
     let self.currentUserName = snapshot.value
})
```

in this example, currentUserName will be populated when Firebase has gathered the value and returned it in the snapshot. It's ONLY valid when the code block {} executes.

So expanding on that, inside the block you are free to work with the returned data

```
{ snapshot in
         let self.currentUserName = snapshot.value as! String
         or
         self.myTextField.StringValue = snapshot.value as! String
         or
         self.myNameArray.append(snapshot.value)
})
```

To answer the initial question: If you define a var outside the block it's good practice to reference it with self. (it's also easier to read)

*you can kinda return data but that's not really how it was designed to work and that falls outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did get the concept, so the code inside the block {} will not able to run faster than the outside one, so it will not get modified right ?  But i am trying to sepreate all the backend code and viewcontroller on that way i can call functions multiple time rather than copy paste big chunk of firebase code many times.  How can i do that ? like pass a id of some user and get a user object out ?

Comment: Change your thinking. Say for example; you want to get some user info and then display it on a view controller. Query firebase for that data and then within the block, populate and display the viewController. Don't think of firebase as a function as that will get you into trouble. It doesn't return values and doesn't have a method to do returns of any kind. The data from Firebase is viable ONLY inside the block and you should not do anything with he data until that block executes.

Comment: Oh - quick example. Populating a tableView that's on a view controller: The sequence would be: display the viewController (with the tableview). query firebase for data. INSIDE THE BLOCK assign that data from the snapshot to an array to be the tableView datasource. Fully populate the array, and then call tableView.reloadData. All done inside the firebase block

Comment: So i wont able to separate backend and front end using firebase?

Comment: That's kind of a vague question. However, things like queries are pretty specific so a query to get a user name from the /users node would be very different than a query to get all dinosaurs that are between 5 and 8 feet tall. Your queries are built around your data so it would be challenging (with any database) to craft a single query for all query types (and probably unnecessary). Additionally Firebase works with observers and those observers observer different nodes for different info, so again, crafting a single observer for all data types wouldn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: @EdwardDu Great! If you run into any issues after your code is updated, please ask another question so we can lend a hand. Oh, and if my answer helped you and provided direction, please accept it as others may find it useful as well.