# How to get chronologically latest post from Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on app in which Facebook like news feed is used,and i am using Firebase as a database. Everything is working fine, I just need to fetch posts, time wise.

```
FIRDatabaseQuery * query = [[[_firebaseReference child:@"Demo"]child:@"posts"]queryLimitedToFirst:100];

[query observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        postsDictionary = snapshot.value;
        [self createSocialAppDataSource];
    }
}];
```

The data in postsDictionary is same as in Database,But i want that data (post) to get sorted respect to time,So how to use query?

structure of my post in database as follow

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it'll be hard to do more than point you to the [Firebase Database documentation for sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: i've edited my question, please take a look

Comment: Please post the JSON as actual JSON text, which you can get by clicking the Export JSON link from your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/).

Comment: Aside from that, it looks like `query.queryOrdered(byChild:"dateTime")` and then a loop over the snapshot should do the trick. Did you read the documentation for queries? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sort_data

Comment: yes i do,but i am not getting idea how does it exactly works..!Thats why i need help..!with firebase queries

Answer (score 1):

To filter the nodes on a child property, call `queryOrderedByChild`.

Then when you execute the query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So you'll need to loop over the children:

```
FIRDatabaseQuery * query = [[[[_firebaseReference child:@"Demo"] child:@"posts"] queryOrderedByChild: "dateTime"] queryLimitedToFirst:100];

[query observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    for ( FDataSnapshot *child in snapshot.children) {

        NSLog(@"child.key = %@",child.key);

    }
}];
```

Loosely based on my answer here: [IOS Firebase: Loop all key in snapshot.value get messy position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734164/ios-firebase-loop-all-key-in-snapshot-value-get-messy-position)

Comment: Okay i'll try this..!

Answer (score 0):

Usually people append the array they are feeding into the `collectionView` or `tableView`  (for example) but in your case you can `[myMutableArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:0];` now when you enumerate through your `snapshot` each post will be added to the front of your `array`

Comment: Thank you for replay..thats not the problem, i am already storing snapshot.value into dictionary, i just need to sort every post as latest respect to time

Comment: Dont you create an array of your dictionary? If you have many posts then it would be an array of your data and that is when you sort it. I also take a snapshot and put it into a dictionary then I append an array and I can get the latest posts in order.

Comment: Did you create a class to hold the post data?